# How to check react query has a new dataset?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am using react-query to fetch the data within my application. I have written a custom hook to fetch the data.

```
export const useFilteredAudits = (config = {}) => {
const [
    {
        startDate,
        endDate,
        searchTerm,
        offset,
        sort
    }
] = useSearchParams();

const {data, ...rest} = useAudits(
    {
        searchTerm,
        issueDateFrom: startDate,
        issueDateTo: endDate,

        limit: 100,
        offset: offset,
        sort,
    },
    {...config}
);

  return {data: data?.items, metaData: data?.metaData, ...rest};
};
```

The above hook will be listing to the URL search parameter and will fetch the latest data when parameters are changed.

Now, I want to know when the new data is fetched.

to check the, I added a useEffect as below

```
const {data: fetchedAuditData, metaData, isFetching} = useFilteredAudits();

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("New Data")

},[fetchedAuditData])
```

But the console log inside the `useEffect` will not be executed until query cache time is over. When I print the `fetchedAuditData` outside of the `useEffect` I can see updated data. But I am wondering why `useEffect`is not catching the latest change.

However when I set `{cacheTime:0}` in my query, `console.log` inside useEffect will be printed.

```
const {data: fetchedAuditData, metaData, isFetching} = useFilteredAudits({cacheTime: 0});
```

Can someone explain to me why is this happening?

Comment: Well the effect should execute once immediately with undefined, so the best explanation would be that `data?.items` is always undefined. It would be easier if you’d provide a codesandbox reproduction.